# Why is $\det(e^A)$ equal to $\det(e^A)$ = $\prod_{i=1}^n e^{\lambda_i}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have been trying to solve why the determinant of $e^A$ is equal to $e^{\operatorname{Tr}(A)}$, but get stuck, as I cannot prove why $\det(e^A)$ = $\prod_{i=1}^n e^{\lambda_i}.$

Comment: The determinant is the product of the eigenvalues and the eigenvalues of $e^A$ are $e^{\lambda_1},\ldots,e^{\lambda_n}$, since $$e^{A}=I+A+\frac{A^2}{2!}+\frac{A^3}{3!}+\ldots $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Express $A$ as
$$A=P^{-1}UP,$$ with $U$ upper triangular and the eigenvalues $\{\lambda_j\}$ of $A$ on the diagonal.

Then
$$
\mbox{det}\;e^A=\mbox{det}(P^{-1}e^UP)=\mbox{det}\;e^U.
$$

Notice that $e^U$ is upper triangular with $\{e^{\lambda_j}\}$ on the diagonal.

$$
\mbox{det} \;e^A=\mbox{det} \;e^U=e^{\lambda_1}\cdots e^{\lambda_n}=e^{\lambda_1+\ldots+\lambda_n}.
$$

Comment: Thank you, but what I am having trouble with is is your final step. how does $\det(e^U)$ = e^Tr(U)? I cannot seem to figure this out

Comment: $e^U$ is upper triangular, with diagonal entries $e^{\lambda_i}$. 
The determinant of an upper triangular is the product of the diagonal elements, so $e^{\lambda_1} \ldots e^{\lambda_n} = e^{\lambda_1 + \ldots + \lambda_n}$

Answer (score 0):

The determinant is the the product of the eigenvalues. If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $e^{\lambda}$ is an eigenvalue of $e^{A}$.  The product of the $e^{\lambda}_{i}$'s can be written
$$
\prod_{i} e^{\lambda}_{i} = e^{\sum_{i} {\lambda}_{i}}.
$$
The sum in the exponent is the trace of $A$.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that about eigenvalues and how e^\lambda is an eigenvalue of e^A

Comment: Now that this fact has been stated, you can (and should) test it directly.  First, verify that for every nonnegative integer $k$, $\lambda^{k}$ is an eigenvalue of $A^{k}$.  Next, use the definition
$$
e^{A} = \sum_{k \geq 0} {1 \over k!} A^{k}.
$$